# How to include custom CSS or Javascript on a Content Item in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

Sometimes I want to add some custom CSS or Javascript to a page but the HTML editor doesn't handle this gracefully, even when using text dialog.

I could use an alternate view but then I have to upload the view file to my host every edit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a module (Vandelay.Classy) that does exactly this.

http://orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Vandelay.Classy

Comment: That project has been updated to http://orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Vandelay.Industries

Comment: https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Vandelay.Industries