# How to include a css stylesheet in Orchard module?

Tags: css, orchardcms

I am working on a module for Orchard, and I just want to know how to include a css file.

I have done the following with no result:

Added a folder "Styles" to the root of my module and included a stylesheet and a Web.config file like in [this](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/260443) question.

And I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807939/how-to-include-custom-css-or-javascript-on-a-content-item-in-orchard) but that's not what I am looking for.

EDIT:

Ok, solution:

When I started working on Orchard I created a new module by just creating a new project in `Orchard.Web/Modules` folder, but as I read [here](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/240340), my `Views/Web.config` file has to include some orchard base things what mine didn't because I did not create the module using codegen. I fixed it now by replacing my `Web.config` file for a `Web.config` file from another Orchard module, now it works.

Next time I will use codegen to create a new module.

Thanks to endorphin for helping me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to include your stylesheet in a view, you need to specify this at the top of your view. Where the name of your stylesheet is the filename of the .css file in the Styles folder.

So in your .cshtml file for your view..

```
@{
  Style.Include("your-stylesheet.css").AtHead();
}
```

I have used `AtHead()` in the past, but there are other methods to include your stylesheet in different locations (such as `AtFoot()`)

If your stylesheet depends on other stylesheets you can do something a little more interesting by creating a Resource Manifest which is detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6500121/580101

Comment: Ok thanks, so I have seen that when I was searching for this, but I don't know what reference or something to add in order to use `Style.Include()`?

Comment: `Style.Include()` is within Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceRegister. You should not need to include any references to use this, I never do.

Comment: Weird, because when I just use `Style.Include()` I get "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Style' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Hmm. It looks like some kind of a Web.config problem, found someone with the same problem [here](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/240340). Gonna look at that now and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, works now, check the question for what I did. Thank you, endorphin!

Comment: AtHead and AtFoot are for scripts, and are meaningless for stylesheets.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Is there a clean way to override this behaviour? I would like to require stylesheets AtFoot.

Comment: But stylesheets go into the head, not the body.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy My bad, I misunderstood a recommendation to defer loading of blocking stylesheets. Though it's technically possible to put them in the body, I realise now that the correct approach is to append them to the head using javascript.