# How to style the 'blog' in orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

How can I style the 'Blog' for which I added via Orchard CMS dashboard.

For some reason, this section: Once added, adds fine, but is just black & white with 0 styles included from the rest of the site. I'm trying to figure out how to style this with the rest of the site.

With the `/Styles/`

Folder I have tried:

```
/menu.blog-admin.css
/orchard-blogs-admin.css
/orchard-blogs-archives.css
```

But none of these styles I've added to any of these files rendered. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start will be in [Orchard Docs](http://docs.orchardproject.net)

1. You will need to add your styles, script and other content as Orchard Resources, by implementing `IResourceManifestProvider` and adding your styles. Then in, your blog views you can use `Style.Require('YourStyle')`. 
   Here's how in this [page](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Getting-Started-with-Modules-Part-4#Yourstylesshouldntbeinline) of Orchard Docs
2. Use [Shape Tracing](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools) to identify files which you may wish to override
3. Read about [Alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates)

To quickly just add a style try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13720825/588894)

Comment: Wow, seems like a bit much for styling a new component.. but thanks, I'll give this a shout.

Comment: Do you only want to style an existing html file?

Comment: Try this `@{ Style.Include("menu.blog-admin.css").AtHead(); }`

Comment: It's for the /blog which file can I add that? this one: BlogArchivesViewModel.cs ?

Comment: No, you have to add it to your *.cshtml view files. If you want to use these styles for the whole site, you can then place it in `Layout.cshtml`

Comment: `Orchard.Web\Themes\TheThemeMachine\Views` or whatever respective theme you are using :)